# unable to access Linux VM on Azure

Tags: linux, azure, cloud, oracle-linux

I recently uploaded Oracle Linux 6 VM from VM Warework station to Azure. After provisioning the VM , I am unable to connect to the VM via SSH through Putty. "Network Error: Connection Timed Out" is the error. I uploaded this VM with DHCP ON. Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you cross check the ip address of the VM you're trying to connect from the azure dashboard? Also, make sure that the end point for ssh is open in vm configuration in azure dashboard

Comment: did you install the linux agent before uploading the vhd?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't setup WAAgent on your Linux before uploading your VHD, it can be a reason. Check also your Network Security Group if SSH is open on Internet. There is a good article that sumarize how to create and upload a Linux Image to Azure : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-create-upload-vhd/

last but not least, you can also use Boot Diagnostic on Microsoft Azure Portal to check Startup of your VM

Regards

Stanislas